# Is it possible to use WCF in a .Net Core 2 console application?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

I haven't problems for .Net Framework, but I need to use WCF in .NET Core 2. I need to host WCF services in my console application.

On the base of [this](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2366) post I assume that it is possible in .NET Core 2 but I can't find any info how to do it in .NET Core 2. I would be very grateful for the links to expanded info.

Comment: Server or client? (hosting vs consuming WCF services)

Comment: I need to host WCF services in my console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hosting WCF services is not supported in .NET Core 2.0. The support libraries allow consuming WCF services, but not hosting.

You can follow [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1200) tracking the feature request for server-side WCF: